# How can I leverage Named Credentials?

Tags: integration, soap, namedcredentials

I am doing a POC for a point to point integration between Salesforce & SAP. I have to make callouts to SAP's SOAP services. The SAP team has provided me a WSDL file, the body block of WSDL expects the request in following format. I was also provided a generic user's credentials.

```
<soapenv:Body>
      <urn:ZfmRfiAccStmtVer3>
         <Budat>2016-02-28</Budat>
         <Bukrs></Bukrs>
         <Gjahr></Gjahr>
         <Kunnr>000000786</Kunnr>
         <LtOutput>
            <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
            <item>
               <Vbeln></Vbeln>
               <Belnr></Belnr>
               <Bldat></Bldat>
               <Budat></Budat>
               <Blart></Blart>
               <Ltext></Ltext>
               <Lifnr></Lifnr>
               <Kunnr></Kunnr>
            </item>
         </LtOutput>
      </urn:ZfmRfiAccStmtVer3>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

I was able to successfully test the service on SoapUI since it has the provision to provide the username & password in the request properties.

I peformed WSDL2apex and generated the apex classes. I tried invoking the web service using anonymous. Since the request body of the Web service is not designed to take the Username & Password. Can I leverage the Named Credential in apex class to provide the username & password? If yes, please advise how with an example.

[image]

Comment: Help docs provide good example (Help docs now in Lightning -cool) https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=named_credentials_about.htm&type=0

Comment: @Bennie Check this http://blog.enree.co/2016/03/salesforce-apex-lets-play-with-named.html